Problema para tomar valor vendedores en ERP de python
Vereis estoy de prácticas en una empresa que trabajan con un ERP de python 2.7 (la versión antigua) pero es la que tiene el cliente.
El caso es que me pidieron que sacase las comisiones por vendedor y no hubo problema.
Pero en el informe de comisiones, solo aparece el vendedor 002, de los 6 que hay.
elif accion=='a_inf01':     
    fecd=valor_preg(preguntas,'%FECD')
    fech=valor_preg(preguntas,'%FECH')
    vd=valor_preg(preguntas,'%VD')
    if vd<>'':
        ls_vendedores=vd.split('?')
    else:
        ls_vendedores=claves(gpx,'vendedores')

    if fecd in ['',None]:error(cl,'Indique fecha desde.')
    if fech in ['',None]:error(cl,'Indique fecha hasta.')

    pgs=[]
    pgs.append(['RM_FEC','>=',fecd])
    pgs.append(['RM_FEC','<=',fech])
    remesas=selec(gpx,'remesas','0 RM_COB',pgs)

    dc_comis_pves={}
    dc_total_comision={}

    for nrm,cobros in remesas:
        for ln in cobros:
            ncb=ln[0]

            cobro=lee(cl,gpx,'cobros',ncb)
            if cobro==1:continue

            for nfr,impocob in cobro<CB_FRAS>:
                dc_total_comision=Calcula_Comision_Factura(nfr,dc_total_comision,ls_vendedores)
    rs,dc_cab=[],{}
    for nfr,ven in dc_total_comision.keys():
        comision,ffr,ccl,deno_cl,fe_ttt=dc_total_comision[nfr,ven]
        if abs(comision)==0.0:continue
        fila=Busca_Fila(rs,[ven,nfr],8,('l','l','d','d','l','l','2','2'))
        factura=lee(cl,gpx,'facturas-e',nfr)
        if factura==1:continue
        bruto=factura<FE_BRU>
        dcob=factura<FE_DCOB>
        for ncob,impo in dcob:
            cobro=lee(cl,gpx,'cobros',ncob)
            if cobro==1:continue
            if cobro<CB_EST><>'R':continue
            fec_cob=cobro<CB_FREM>

        rs[fila][2]=ffr
        rs[fila][3]=fec_cob
        rs[fila][4]=ccl
        rs[fila][5]=deno_cl
        rs[fila][6]=bruto
        rs[fila][7]=comision


            if dc_cab.has_key((0,ven))==0:
            vendedor=lee(cl,gpx,'vendedores',ven)
            deno_vd='No existe vendedor'
            if vendedor<>1:deno_vd=vendedor<VD_DENO>
            dc_cab[0,ven]=ven+' - '+deno_vd
    rs=ordena(rs,[0,1])
    ##$>dc_cab, ven, res, rs
    self.envia(cl,(rs,dc_cab))

Por alguna razón, que no logro descubrir, por ejemplo, ls_vendedores al poner un punto de inspección me recoge los códigos de cada vendedor:
[ "000",  "001",  "002", "003",  "004", "005", "006"]

pero vendedor solo me recoge esto: (que es el vendedor asociado al código 002
["JAUME", "",  "",  "",  "",  "",  "",  "",  "",  "", [],  [],  [],  "",  0.0]

Mientras que ven coge el código solo del vendedor 1 (001)
Si alguien pudiera ayudarme le estaría eternamente agradecido.

En python la indentación es la que define los bloques. La línea if dc_cab.has_key... está fuera del ciclo for, por lo que se va a ejecutar una sola vez. Mi sospecha es que ese sea el origen del problema por el que ves un solo vendedor.

está dentro del bloque, no sé por que aquí se indentó mal.
Muchas gracias igualmente por tomarte tu tiempo en contestarme amigo :)

sugiero entonces que des clic en [edit] y corrijas el código de la pregunta, para evitar esa confusión.
